# Get value of checkboxes in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have some html checkboxes on a page and I need to verify that they have been check in the postback event for the page.

The data for these checkboxes is not stored in a database, they just have to be checked before the use can go to the next page.

How do i verify that they are checked?  I don't see them in the Request.Form.AllKeys collection

```
<input id='terms_eligibility' type='checkbox'   />
<input id='terms_accurate' type='checkbox' />
<input id='terms_score_release' type='checkbox' />
```

---

EDIT
Here's what I ended up doing

View

```
 @Html.CheckBox("terms_eligibility")
```

Controller

```
string eligibility = Request.Form.GetValues("terms_eligibility")[0];
```

Comment: you haven't specified any `value` AND the "checkbox" won't show in the `Form` collection if it wasn't selected ...

Comment: @RonaldMcDonald why don't you have a view model for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a HTML checkbox is not checked then its value is not sent back to the webserver.

MVC solves this problem by adding an `<input type="hidden" />` for each checkbox which ensures that a value is always sent, so it can detect if a checkbox was checked or not.

To use these hidden inputs you must use the `Html.CheckBox` or `Html.CheckBoxFor` helper methods.

Anyway, the HTML you posted doesn't have any `name=""` attributes. HTML inputs must have a name attribute. They don't use the `id` attribute for form field keys.

Comment: Adding hidden values causes other issues.
The main problem here is the lack of name attributes.

Comment: What other issues? Adding hidden fields is what ASP.NET MVC does by-design and it's a great way to ensure that a field exists even if its value was not sent. Ruby on Rails and CakePHP both do the same thing.

Comment: string eligibility = Request.Form.GetValues("terms_eligibility")[0];

Answer (score 8):

With MVC you should be using a view model to track the checkbox states e.g.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool TermsEligibility { get; set; }
    public bool TermsAccurate { get; set; } 
    public bool TermsScoreRelease { get; set; }
}
```

Let MVC map the property to the controls:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myFormId" })
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.TermsElibility)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.TermsAccurate)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.TermsScoreRelease)   
    <input id="saveBtn" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

You can then access the values from your model when you post the results:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (model.TermsEligibility)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: UpVote for using MVC how it's meant to be used.